Method with return Task throws BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection
I am using Dapper with the following code,
public async Task<T> QuerySingleAsync<T>(string sql)
{
    return await connection.QuerySingleAsync<T>(sql);
}

This method is called by,
public async Task<int> GetData1()
{
    return await aboveClass.QuerySingleAsync<int>(GET_DATA_SQL);
}

This method called by,
public Task<int> GetData2()
{
    return aboveClass.GetData1();
}

and then it is awaited,
var messages = await GetData2();

It thorws,
System.InvalidOperationException: BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(Boolean isAsync, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQueryInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, AsyncCallback callback, Object stateObject, Int32 timeout, Boolean inRetry, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImplAsync(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Object param) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 678

If I changed the method to,
This method called by,
public async Task<int> GetData2()
{
    return await aboveClass.GetData1();
}

It works. Is eliding async/await have impact?

GetData2 here should work similarly enough; I would feel pretty comfortable removing that async/await, and it causing a problem would surprise me - unless there's something we can't see relating to the lifetime of the connection, in particular a using - can you show the lifetime of the connection here? Another possibility would be related to threading/concurrency and the connection being available to multiple threads - is that a possibility?

Something interesting here is the end of the first line of the message: "System.InvalidOperationException: BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open." - so it is open but not available; I'm suspicious that this does relate to concurrent usage; do you have a minimal repro that shows this happening (btw: for context, I wrote Dapper; I can probably help a little)

I think I was victim of https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/
My IJob is Singleton which have scoped dependency.
I changed it to use new DI scope in the IJob

So: indirect concurrency - I'm glad you found the problem, and also glad that my hunch was right!
